# vb.net - How do I selectively communicate with two instances of a program?

Tags: vb.net, multiple-instances, system.diagnostics

I'm new to VB, and so forgive me if this is a simple question.

I will be running multiple time consuming (single thread) processes in a program (that allows automation thru COM). And so to save some time, I want to open two or more instances of this program and run them simultaneously. But anything that I try to do on the program, it happens on the first opened program. This is what I have which my intentions are to open two instances of the program (which does correctly), and open a new document in each of the instances (which what it does is open two new documents in myProcess0 and none in myProcess1. Note: I have System.Diagnostics namespace activated.

```
    Using myProcess0 As Process = Process.Start(programPath)
        myProcess0.WaitForInputIdle()
        pws0 = New COMprogram.Document
    End Using

    Using myProcess1 As Process = Process.Start(programPath)
        myProcess1.WaitForInputIdle()
        pws1 = New COMprogram.Document
    End Using
```

Note: The COM program does not allow to create an handle for the program (like Matlab allows with MLApp.MLApp)

Any help will be appreciated it! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Document is not pointing to the same file - right?

Comment: DonA: No, it's just like when you go to Word and click "new document." Which I guess it's technically pointing to a "blank" file, but what I mean is that COMprogram.Document is a method to create a new file in the program.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly a solution, but my current "brute" workaround. This works if your iterations are independent of each other and wish to use multiple instances of a program in the same computer to perform these iterations (but for some reason that is unknown to me, any "Application" objects created point back only to the first instance of the Application).

What I'm doing, is tricking the code by using "desktops": http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx

I simply open the VB code and a Application instance in each desktop, and for some reason the VB code only interacts with the Application opened in the current desktop and not on the others. This happens as well with Matlab somehow. For some reason, all Matlab Application objects reference the first instance.

Answer (score 0):

This will be up to the `COMprogram` API. With Word or Excel, for example, you can't specify which instance you're accessing without manipulating an `Application` object.

Comment: Do you think it's a problem of the COMprogram API? This program is still under deveplopment, and emailing with one of the primary developers (which is an engineer not a computer scientist), he mentioned that even when he creates multiple pwrs.Application objects he ends up with all of the handles pointing to the same object. Does this rings any bells?

Comment: @Esteban I haven't needed to work with it to know exactly how, but you probably need to work with `GetObject` rather than `CreateObject` or `New `.